# Using JavaScript to append text after <Input> element within an <li>

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Goal - Append text after the checkbox element in the document

Problem - Currently the textbox doesn't appear within the document. However, it does appear if I set `todoLi.appendChild(checkbox)`after `todoLi.textContent = todo.todoText` but this isn't my desired state. I want the checkbox to append before the `.textcontent` of the `<li>`

**Code**

```js
const todoList = {
   
  todos: [],

  addTodo: function(todoText){
    this.todos.push({
      todoText: todoText,
      completed: false
    })
  }
}

const views = {

  displayTodos: function(){
    const todosContainer = document.querySelector('#todosContainer')

    if(todoList.todos.length === 0){
      const message = document.createElement('p')
      message.textContent = 'There are currently no todos'
      todosContainer.appendChild(message)
    }else{
      todoList.todos.forEach(function(todo){
        const checkbox = document.createElement('input')
        const todoLi = document.createElement('li')
        checkbox.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox')

        todoLi.appendChild(checkbox)
        todoLi.textContent = todo.todoText
        todosContainer.appendChild(todoLi)
      })
    }
  }
}

views.displayTodos()
```

```html
<ul id="todosContainer"></ul>
```

Comment: what is `todo`?

Comment: Your snippet doesn't work, btw.

Comment: use `innerHTML += todo.todoText` instead of `textContent`

Comment: Do this resolve? https://jsfiddle.net/6bexyLu4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const todoList = {
  todos: [{
    todoText: 'text1'
  }]
}

todoList.todos.forEach(function(todo) {
  const checkbox = document.createElement('input')
  const todoLi = document.createElement('li')
  checkbox.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox')

  todoLi.appendChild(checkbox);
  todoLi.appendChild(document.createTextNode(todo.todoText));
  todosContainer.appendChild(todoLi)
})
```

```html
<ul id="todosContainer"></ul>
```

Comment: *"I want the checkbox to append before the .textcontent"*

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap the the text in `<span>` and add it to `innerHTML`.According to **MDN**

> Setting textContent on a node **removes all of the node's children** and replaces them with a single text node with the given string value

See docs here **[Node.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#Description)**

```js
const checkbox = document.createElement('input')
const todoLi = document.createElement('li')
const todosContainer = document.querySelector('#todosContainer');
checkbox.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox')
let text = "some text"

todoLi.appendChild(checkbox)
todoLi.innerHTML += `<span>${text}</span>`;
todosContainer.appendChild(todoLi)
```

```html
<ul id="todosContainer"></ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the link!